# create a function from a block of code

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

how can I turn this code into a function with the same output?

```
declare
  record_name employees%ROWTYPE; 
begin
  FOR record_name IN (SELECT (a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name) complete_name,
                      b.DEPARTMENT_NAME complete_name2
                     FROM employees a , departments b
                     WHERE ROWNUM < 1000 and a.DEPARTMENT_ID=b.DEPARTMENT_ID)
  LOOP 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name: ' || record_name.complete_name 
                           ||'DEPARTMENT name: '||record_name.complete_name2);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Do you only want to print or do you want the function to return the recordset for further operations? For the former, use the answer @Sajmon gave, replacing the cumulative concatenation with a Put_Line. For the latter, you'll need to create a table-valued function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace function SOME_FUNCTION
RETURN VARCHAR
AS
  record_name employees%ROWTYPE;
  out_stmt varchar(4000); 
  TOO_LONG EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  FOR record_name IN (SELECT (a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name) complete_name,
                      b.DEPARTMENT_NAME complete_name2
                     FROM employees a , departments b
                     WHERE ROWNUM < 1000 and a.DEPARTMENT_ID=b.DEPARTMENT_ID)
  LOOP
    IF (LENGTH(out_stmt) < 4000) THEN
       out_stmt := out_stmt || 'Employee name: ' || record_name.complete_name || 'DEPARTMENT name: '||record_name.complete_name2;
    ELSE
       RAISE TOO_LONG;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  return out_stmt;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN TOO_LONG THEN
      RETURN 'OVERFLOW';
END;
```

Fast example, i don't know whether is some type that not have integrity limitation because not always will be `varchar(4000)` enought. but i heard something about this type but now i dont exactly know wether exists.

When you will work with this in app layer, must somehow format returned string.

Comment: as of Oracle 10g the max varchar is 4000. And also, don't you think the '+' sign won;t work for concatenation? [out_stmt := out_stmt + 'Employee name: '] - should have been ||

Comment: Might want an exception handler in there too, in case you overflow your out_stmt variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE some_employees_record IS RECORD
  (emp_name VARCHAR2(4000)
  ,dept_name VARCHAR2(4000));
CREATE TYPE employees_tab_type IS TABLE OF some_employees_record;

CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION some_employees
RETURN employees_tab_type
PIPELINED
IS
  rec some_employees_record; 
BEGIN
  FOR record_name IN (SELECT (a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name) complete_name,
                      b.DEPARTMENT_NAME complete_name2
                     FROM employees a , departments b
                     WHERE ROWNUM < 1000 and a.DEPARTMENT_ID=b.DEPARTMENT_ID)
  LOOP
    rec.emp_name := record_name.complete_name;
    rec.dept_name := record_name.complete_name2;
    PIPE ROW (rec);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

You can call the above function in two ways. In SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(some_employees);
```

or in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  rt employees_tab_type;
BEGIN
  rt := some_employees;
  FOR i IN 1..rt.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rt(i).emp_name || ', ' || rt(i).dept_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

OT: you do realise that the query returns an effectively random (nondeterministic) set of 999 records, if the number of records exceeds 999?

By the way, this has been done for example purposes only. If your only requirement is for a function to run a query, I wouldn't do it this way. I'd return a ref cursor, or (even better) put the query in a view.